# Xcode 7.2.1 Supporting Files folder missing

Tags: macos, finder, xcode

I am on OS X 10.11.5

and Supporting Files folder is missing

I am following tutorials and they all have that but not in mine

I already tired recreating new projects but it's missing in all of them

Project Creation
1. File > New > Project > iOS . Application > Single View Application

[image: new Project]

[image: Created Project]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Supporting Files` group is not created for Swift-based projects.

For Objective-C-based projects, the folder usually contains `main.m` and maybe `Info.plist` (with related `strings` files).

You can always create your own group named `Supporting Files` and put whatever you want into it.

(Note: the `Supporting Files` entry never was an actual **Folder**, just a **Group** in Xcode)